# Running Open API generator Command for dotnet application in azure pipelines, Unable to query repository, "Request failed with status code 504" error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops

I am Running Open API generator Command for dotnet application in azure pipelines, i am getting Unable to query repository, because of: "Request failed with status code 504" error.. few times its executing successful and few times it´s not.

> Unable to query repository, because of: "Request failed with status
> code 504"

Response:

```
server awselb/2.0
content-type text/html
content-length 132
connection close

/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/main.js:1045
            error.response.data.on('data', data => this.logger.log(data.toString('utf8')));
                                ^

TypeError: error.response.data.on is not a function
    at VersionManagerService.printResponseError (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/main.js:1045:33)
    at /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/main.js:924:18
    at /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/catchError.js:13:51
    at OperatorSubscriber._this._error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:43:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber.error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber._error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber.error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber._error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber.error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber._error (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.19.0/x64/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30
```

basically this command was executed successfully before.. but dont know suddenly its starts giving this error.
i am trying to Generate CLient SDK with the Help of OPEN API Generator. but its getting failed. while running this OPEN API Generator COmmand
here is the command i am trying:

```
script: "openapi-generator-cli generate -g csharp-netcore --additional-properties=prependFormOrBodyParameters=true,targetFramework=net6.0,packageName=Microservice.Sdk -o out -i $(swaggerLocation)/$(appName).v1.json --skip-validate-spec"
```

Comment: I get the same. My node version is 19.4.0

Answer (score 2):

It can be skipped by creating `openapitools.json` file on your working directry.
Contents be like:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "6.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrading node from 19.4.0 to 16.19.0 helped. I am using openapi-generator-cli with node/npm.

Comment: i am using 16.19.0 version of Node.. but still i am getting that error.

Comment: make sure you really use 16.x because I have selected 16.x in /etc/homebrew/...../node but still I had 19.x in /usr/local/bin/node